# Free/libre, accessible, lightweight JavaScript gallery which uses existing HTML5 markup

Tags: open-source, javascript, html, image-viewer, gallery

I have a simple collection of images with (optional) captions in HTML5. Each image could look like:

```
<figure>
  <img src="foobar.png" alt="Alternative text for Foobar">
  <figcaption>Caption for Foobar.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Sometimes some other element than `figure` is used; sometimes a list (`ul`) is used for all `figure` elements; sometimes it’s just `figure` after `figure` without any list.

I’m looking for a JavaScript gallery which makes viewing/exploring these images a nicer experience.

### Features of the gallery

Required:

- Show only one image at a time.
- Offer a simple **navigation** to view the next/previous image and its caption.

  - The caption must not be overlaid!

Optional:

- Clicking on an image opens a **modal** to view it (and its caption) in larger/full size.

  - It should be possible to navigate inside of this modal to the next/previous image, too.
  - Closing this modal should be possible by two ways: pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and clicking a link/button.
- Offer little **preview thumbnails** of all images, allowing to directly jump to a particular image by clicking on it.

Please not:

- Slideshow. Nothing should move automatically.
- Capturing the context menu, or overlaying transparent images. Don’t try to hinder people downloading the images.

### Accessibility requirements

The gallery must be accessible, i.e., following [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/) guidelines.

- **Keyboard users** should be able to use every feature of the gallery.
- It should work for users with weak hardware (just to make sure; I don’t expect a gallery to have a noticeable impact on **performance** anyway).
- It should work on **mobile** devices, too (i.e., touch instead of click; smaller viewport width).

### Technical requirements

The script should **not** require to use specific elements. I want it to use my existing markup (that will be shown when JS is disabled). It should work with **`data-*` attributes** which I add to my markup (`class` would be okay, too, but no `id`!). Any elements needed for the gallery itself (e.g., the navigation buttons) should be added via JS (so that I don’t have to hide them for users without JS support).

Any CSS should be in a **separate CSS** file (I want to copy it into my main stylesheet). No inline styles!

Any JS should be in a separate file (e.g., no inline event handlers), which I’d like to link in the `head`.

The script should be **lightweight**. I don’t want any other features, especially not a full library (no jQuery etc.).

### Licensing requirements

It has to be **FLOSS** (so that [LibreJS](http://www.gnu.org/software/librejs/) users can run it).